# Blue Prism - get collection element without field name

Tags: rpa, blueprism

I have some troubles working with collections, because the field names that are set not always work well (I checked 100 times the names are OK), so I would like to get an element value from the collection by it's index. Something like: Coll(2,3) gives me the 2nd row of the 3rd column.

I know there's a *Read collection field* action, but it needs the field name:

```
If RowIndex < 0 OrElse Coll.Rows.Count <= RowIndex Then
    Throw New ApplicationException("The supplied row index falls outside of the valid range.")
End If

If Not Coll.Columns.Contains(FieldName) Then
   Throw New ApplicationException("The collection does not contain a field with the name '" & FieldName & "'")
End If

Value_Read = CStr(Coll.Rows(RowIndex)(FieldName))
```

How can I replace that FieldName for ColIndex or something like that?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to create a brand new VBO with an action that calls a Code Stage with code similar to the following, that retrieves the value at the specified indices within the `DataTable`:

```
value_out = CStr(coll_in.Rows(CInt(row_index))(CInt(col_index)))
```

In this scenario, you'd have to create the Action, the Action inputs, Action outputs, Code Stage inputs, Code Stage outputs, among other VBO configuration tasks.

---

Alternatively, you can copy/paste the following XML definition into a `.xml` file, and import it into your Blue Prism environment, which will handle a lot of the setup for you:

```
<process name="Utility - Collection Manipulation (enhanced)" version="1.0" bpversion="6.8.0.23415" narrative="" byrefcollection="true" type="object" runmode="Exclusive" preferredid="85cc6944-6bb6-4d9f-80a3-730f6795a0a7">
  <appdef>
    <element name="Application Root">
      <id>b282c66c-7516-49bf-ab60-67ebeecbd1f5</id>
      <type>Application</type>
      <datatype>unknown</datatype>
      <diagnose>False</diagnose>
    </element>
  </appdef>
  <view>
    <camerax>0</camerax>
    <cameray>0</cameray>
    <zoom version="2">1.25</zoom>
  </view>
  <preconditions />
  <endpoint narrative="" />
  <subsheet subsheetid="66499b03-6862-4453-bd13-1a161b85f07d" type="CleanUp" published="True">
    <name>Clean Up</name>
    <view>
      <camerax>0</camerax>
      <cameray>0</cameray>
      <zoom version="2">1.25</zoom>
    </view>
  </subsheet>
  <subsheet subsheetid="fa2065da-c98e-461d-8478-03ae6217eb2a" type="Normal" published="True">
    <name>Get Collection Cell</name>
    <view>
      <camerax>0</camerax>
      <cameray>0</cameray>
      <zoom version="2">1.25</zoom>
    </view>
  </subsheet>
  <stage stageid="47a95b72-9237-4e80-a094-60254bed0627" name="Start" type="Start">
    <loginhibit />
    <display x="15" y="-105" />
    <onsuccess>b10f75e7-f56e-4c2f-84fd-96b0f1c3654a</onsuccess>
  </stage>
  <stage stageid="b10f75e7-f56e-4c2f-84fd-96b0f1c3654a" name="End" type="End">
    <loginhibit />
    <display x="15" y="90" />
  </stage>
  <stage stageid="c8e7d332-e00b-4b36-a264-ea9e1cc18968" name="Stage1" type="ProcessInfo">
    <display x="-195" y="-105" w="150" h="90" />
    <references>
      <reference>System.dll</reference>
      <reference>System.Data.dll</reference>
      <reference>System.Xml.dll</reference>
      <reference>System.Drawing.dll</reference>
      <reference>Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll</reference>
    </references>
    <imports>
      <import>System</import>
      <import>System.Drawing</import>
      <import>System.Data</import>
      <import>System.Collections</import>
    </imports>
    <language>visualbasic</language>
    <globalcode><![CDATA[]]></globalcode>
    <code><![CDATA[]]></code>
  </stage>
  <stage stageid="f703c095-8cf1-4d2f-b9d1-6762853bcdb7" name="Clean Up" type="SubSheetInfo">
    <subsheetid>66499b03-6862-4453-bd13-1a161b85f07d</subsheetid>
    <display x="-195" y="-105" w="150" h="90" />
  </stage>
  <stage stageid="aa0d2e87-fb6d-4705-ad14-c4fca090b773" name="Start" type="Start">
    <subsheetid>66499b03-6862-4453-bd13-1a161b85f07d</subsheetid>
    <loginhibit />
    <display x="15" y="-105" />
    <onsuccess>c4e7cb3b-895e-49a0-8df5-a7c331088eb3</onsuccess>
  </stage>
  <stage stageid="c4e7cb3b-895e-49a0-8df5-a7c331088eb3" name="End" type="End">
    <subsheetid>66499b03-6862-4453-bd13-1a161b85f07d</subsheetid>
    <loginhibit />
    <display x="15" y="90" />
  </stage>
  <stage stageid="a184281e-7d2b-4609-b970-e9d7ce403fe8" name="Get Collection Cell" type="SubSheetInfo">
    <subsheetid>fa2065da-c98e-461d-8478-03ae6217eb2a</subsheetid>
    <display x="-195" y="-105" w="150" h="90" />
  </stage>
  <stage stageid="121240c8-a621-4b66-a0cb-a48a8c0bf66c" name="Start" type="Start">
    <subsheetid>fa2065da-c98e-461d-8478-03ae6217eb2a</subsheetid>
    <loginhibit />
    <display x="15" y="-105" />
    <inputs>
      <input type="collection" name="Collection In" narrative="The collection from which to read the given cell." stage="Collection In" />
      <input type="number" name="Row Index" narrative="The row index from which to read the cell." stage="Row Index" />
      <input type="number" name="Column Index" narrative="The column index from which to read the cell." stage="Column Index" />
    </inputs>
    <onsuccess>41aa3760-b489-4cb2-9c73-040a7c946bdf</onsuccess>
  </stage>
  <stage stageid="0173157c-0b87-4d11-a063-877018291918" name="End" type="End">
    <subsheetid>fa2065da-c98e-461d-8478-03ae6217eb2a</subsheetid>
    <loginhibit />
    <display x="15" y="90" />
    <outputs>
      <output type="text" name="Cell Value" narrative="The value read from the cell at the specified indices." stage="Cell Value" />
    </outputs>
  </stage>
  <stage stageid="ad6b171c-3666-4b39-80bb-7b002d941911" name="Note1" type="Note">
    <subsheetid>66499b03-6862-4453-bd13-1a161b85f07d</subsheetid>
    <narrative>Clean Up Page

This is an optional page where you might choose to perform some finalisation (or "cleanup") tasks as your business object is closed down.

The cleanup action will be called automatically immediately after closing your business object at the end of a business process.

You will not be able to call this action from a business process, nor will it be called at any other time than before the disposal of the business object.</narrative>
    <display x="-180" y="60" w="180" h="230" />
  </stage>
  <stage stageid="b726df4a-77b4-463d-8b12-949b1b8653b5" name="Note2" type="Note">
    <narrative>Initialise Page

This is an optional page where you might choose to perform some initialisation tasks after your business object is loaded.

The initialise action will be called automatically immediately after loading your business object.

You will not be able to call this action from a business process, nor will it be called at any other time than after the creation of the object.</narrative>
    <display x="-180" y="60" w="180" h="230" />
  </stage>
  <stage stageid="c2d6c2f7-b765-425f-8a46-2d0ebaeb69a1" name="Collection In" type="Collection">
    <subsheetid>fa2065da-c98e-461d-8478-03ae6217eb2a</subsheetid>
    <display x="-195" y="-15" w="150" h="60" />
    <datatype>collection</datatype>
    <private />
    <alwaysinit />
  </stage>
  <stage stageid="78c5c116-5ff2-4c02-a599-7c860ef84035" name="Row Index" type="Data">
    <subsheetid>fa2065da-c98e-461d-8478-03ae6217eb2a</subsheetid>
    <display x="-195" y="30" w="150" h="30" />
    <datatype>number</datatype>
    <initialvalue />
    <private />
    <alwaysinit />
  </stage>
  <stage stageid="03368ae5-05d1-4f9b-96b9-89e141228cc0" name="Column Index" type="Data">
    <subsheetid>fa2065da-c98e-461d-8478-03ae6217eb2a</subsheetid>
    <display x="-195" y="60" w="150" h="30" />
    <datatype>number</datatype>
    <initialvalue />
    <private />
    <alwaysinit />
  </stage>
  <stage stageid="41aa3760-b489-4cb2-9c73-040a7c946bdf" name="GetCellValue" type="Code">
    <subsheetid>fa2065da-c98e-461d-8478-03ae6217eb2a</subsheetid>
    <loginhibit />
    <display x="15" y="-15" />
    <inputs>
      <input type="collection" name="coll_in" expr="[Collection In]" />
      <input type="number" name="row_index" expr="[Row Index]" />
      <input type="number" name="col_index" expr="[Column Index]" />
    </inputs>
    <outputs>
      <output type="text" name="value_out" stage="Cell Value" />
    </outputs>
    <onsuccess>0173157c-0b87-4d11-a063-877018291918</onsuccess>
    <code><![CDATA[value_out = CStr(coll_in.Rows(CInt(row_index))(CInt(col_index)))]]></code>
  </stage>
  <stage stageid="07759f58-4446-485b-bcba-3cf8aef21357" name="Cell Value" type="Data">
    <subsheetid>fa2065da-c98e-461d-8478-03ae6217eb2a</subsheetid>
    <display x="-195" y="105" w="150" h="30" />
    <datatype>text</datatype>
    <initialvalue />
    <private />
    <alwaysinit />
  </stage>
</process>
```